# Transformation sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The sentence : I don't like her, even though I admire her achievements . Can I transform this sentence like this: Much admiring her achievements may be , I don't like her. Is my sentence correct grammatically or wrong?  Please explain clearly and comprehensible.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No, your sentence is not correct. I think what you are looking for is

> As admirable as her achievements may be, I don't like her.

or

> As much as I admire her achievements, I don't like her.

You can't say

> Much admiring her achievements may be

because you are trying to use *admiring*, a verb, to qualify a noun. You also can't use *much*, an adjective, to qualify a verb like *admiring*. That phrase just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? I use  *admiring* as an adj  so  as to qualify the noun  achievement  . Why can't I use much for this sentence?

Comment: You cannot use _admiring_ as an adjective to qualify achievements in that way. If you say that _a glance is admiring/an admiring glance_, you mean that the glance is **full of admiration for something/someone**. You can not say that _an achievement is admiring_ because then you would be saying that the achievement is full of admiration for something. That makes no sense because an achievement can be admired but it can't be the one doing the admiring. If you want to qualify the noun _achievement_ you must use _admirable_ to show that you are directing admiration at the achievement.

Comment: So can I ask you another question? Can I use admiring to qualify or state a person like in this sentence :*she is such a admiring person that deserves respect* or I replace * admiring * and use * admirable* .Thank you very much . So confusing @'@

Comment: @NhiHoang You must replace _admiring_ with _admirable_. This is the rule: when you use _admiring_ to qualify a noun, you mean that that noun is admiring something else and when you use _admirable_ to qualify a noun you mean that that noun is worthy of being admired. In the phrase _she is such an admiring person_, you are saying that _she_ is admiring something/someone else but in _she is such an admirable person_ you are saying that she is worthy of being admired. So what you want to say is that _she is such an **admirable** person that deserves respect_.

Comment: @NhiHoang The difference between _admiring_ and _admirable_ is the noun to whom the admiration is being directed. Does this answer your question? Feel free to ask more if you still have any other questions.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.btw, thanks a lot for sparing time to help me .^:^

Comment: @NhiHoang You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer as the best answer if it has helped you.